# how to include color gradient for two variables

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, group-by

My dataset for chrom 1 looks something like this

```
head(data)
  SNP     BP       P    Dataset          LD
1  SNP1 541095 0.00529 expression 0.000610863
2  SNP2 541095 0.07897   original 0.066610863
3  SNP3 541133 0.21990   original 0.040534557
4  SNP4 541233 0.47890 expression 0.008216450
5  SNP5 541260 0.39790   original 0.010310200
6  SNP6 541260 0.19210 expression 0.000390915
7  SNP7 541265 0.000001 original 1
7  SNP7 541265 0.00001 expression 1
```

I want to overlay the two datasets into one plot and also show the LD correlation of SNP7 with the other SNPs.

So far, this is what I could come up with

```
  Position<-data$BP/1E6
  ggplot(data, aes(x=Position, y=-log10(P), color=Dataset, shape=Dataset)) +
  geom_point(size=4) + xlim(540101/1E6,1565570/1E6) + ylim(0,10) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=7), color="#a50f15")
```

I am not being able to group the variants according to gradient color based on LD, it shows just one color for both the datasets instead

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Position, y=-log10(P), colour=LD, shape=Dataset)) +
 geom_point(size=4) + xlim(540101/1E6,1565570/1E6) + ylim(0,10) +
 geom_hline(aes(yintercept=7), color="#a50f15")
```

Is it possible to

1) Change the color of the dataset Original to red and expression to blue

2) make groups based on LD values

```
       LD values   dataset   color     dataset   color
group1 0 to 0.2    original  light blue  expression light red
group2 0.2 to 0.4  original  .         expression .
group3 0.4 to 0.6  original  .         expression .
group4 0.6 to 0.8  original  .         expression .
group5 0.8 to 1.0  original  dark blue expression dark red
```

Many thanks

Comment: There is no column `Position` in your `data`, so your code doesn't run.

Comment: Also, does "low blue" mean "light blue" and "high blue" mean dark blue??

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include a code, so I converted              `Position<-data$BP/1E6` yes low blue and high blue is light and dark blue